# Java Cassandra QueryBuilder now() for timestamp fields

Tags: java, cassandra, query-builder, cql

Working with the datastax Cassandra QueryBuilder, is there any way to insert `now()` into a timestamp column?

The current implementation does not have a `dateOf` or `toUnixTimestamp` function. The `now()`function itself returns `timeuuid` which is incompatible with timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may depend on the version of the driver...

For driver 3.x, there is a generic [`fcall` method](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.8/manual/statements/built/#selecting-data) that allows you to call any function, something like this (didn't check, but you get an idea):

```java
.fcall("toTimestamp", now())
```

For driver 4.x, there is similar [`function` call](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.9/manual/query_builder/select/#functions).  You even have the possibility to use raw code snippets.